# Grafana-server keeps connect and send data to some external addresses

Tags: ubuntu, hacking, grafana

I am running a Grafana-server on an Ubuntu 15 server.  It seems to keep connecting to 151.101.*.133:443.  I have identified a few and listed below.  When I connect to the address manually from a browser, it returns a Github.io SSL certificate.  Of course, the browser would block it because it doesn't match with the URL.

Version Installed: grafana/wheezy,now 3.1.1-1470047149 amd64 [installed]

Here are the addresses I have identified

- 151.101.20.133/32
- 151.101.56.133/32
- 151.101.32.133/32
- 151.101.116.133/32

Comment: IMHO, this question belongs to Grafana bugtracker (after a brief examination I suppose it requests [some internal metrics from here](https://api.github.com/repos/hawkular/hawkular.github.io/contents/?ref=swagger)

Answer (score 0):

After setting followings in the config.ini, grafana-server stopped connecting to random addresses

reporting_enabled = false
check_for_updates = false